# Multiple natural keys for Django Serializer

Tags: python, django

Consider I have he following model:

```
class BankLoan(models.Model):
    amount=models.IntegerField()
    issued_to_account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    issued_by = models.ForeignKey(BankOfficer)
    issue_date = models.DateField()
```

For Django's serializer, it looked like I could only have 1 `natural_key`. However, my scenario calls for 2 foreign key. Could anybody help for this?

Comment: I don't think Django's default serializer *doesn't* allow for multiple `foreignkeys`. Can you link me to or inform me of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake when asking this question.

Consider I have a BankLoan object

```
class BankLoan(models.Model):
    amount=models.IntegerField()
    issued_to_account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    issued_by = models.ForeignKey(BankOfficer)
    issue_date = models.DateField()
```

And with Django Serializer, I want the JSON output to be

```
{
'pk' : 1, 
'amount' : 100.00, 
'issued_to_account' : 'john.doe', 
'issued_by' : 'bank_teller_jane',
'issue_date' : '2016-06-20 12:00:00'
}
```

I should be relying on the `natural_key` method of the related models, instead of focusing on changing stuff on the `serializer`. In other words:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    def natural_key(self):
        return self.username
```

and so on